# Using forms authentication, is it possible to switch the logged in user in code, just for the current request?

Tags: asp.net-membership, forms-authentication, membership

In a certain situation, I want a request to execute as a user different than the one actually logged in.  So, when User A requests a particular page, from code I want to switch it execute under the user account of User B -- *only for this single request* (or even for a single block of code...)

I've used this:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie("UserB")
```

This works, but it's persistent.  When I request a new page, I'm now logged in as User B, which is not what I want.

Is this possible?  I've RTFM'd up and down for this.

**Edit:** I may have found an answer, which I posted below.  Looking for confirmation or refutation of this solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think I might have found it.  I'm not 100% sure, but this works.  I just don't know if it's completely correct or if there's something I'm not considering.

```
HttpContext.Current.User = PrincipalInfo.CreatePrincipal("UserB");
```

Again, this seems to do what I originally wanted.  If you have experience that would prove me right or wrong, please comment.